# Get image src from html element

Tags: php, preg-match, simple-html-dom

Inside my HTML I have this `<link rel="image_src" href="data/20/1.jpg" />`

I need to retrieve the href (`data/20/1.jpg`).

I tried the code below without any luck

```php
function fetch_rel($url)
{
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $dom = new DomDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($data);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    # query metatags with og prefix
    $metas = $xpath->query('//*/link[starts-with(@rel, \'image_src\')]');

    $og = array();

    foreach($metas as $meta){
        # get property name without og: prefix
        $property = str_replace('image_src', '', $meta->getAttribute('rel'));
        # get content
        $content = $meta->getAttribute('href');
        $og[$property] = $content;
    }

    return $og;
}
$og = fetch_rel($u);
$image_src = $og['image_src'];
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please show an example of input and how output should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've made just a little error:

You try to access `$og['image_src'];`, but your array has no index `image_src`, because you **replaced** image_src with **''**.

**You have to replace this line:**

```
# get property name without og: prefix <-- By the way: you have no og: prefix ;)
$property = str_replace('image_src', '', $meta->getAttribute('rel'));
```

**with this:**

```
$property = $meta->getAttribute('rel');
```